# C# - extracting values from JSON object with "System" in property names

Tags: c#, json

At the beginning I want to say that 'm not a C# developer by any means, however at my work I've received a task where I have to write simple web service in .net.
The task is not very complicated however I've encountered the problem that JSON payload which is sent to our web service has "System" in property names:

```
"resource": {
        "fields": {
            "System.AreaPath": "someData",
            "System.TeamProject": "someData",
            "System.IterationPath": "someData"
         }
}
```

I'm trying to get those values by using:

```
    public class Resource
    {
        public Fields System.AreaPath { get; set; }
    }
```

However I'm getting an error ("System" is a namespace but used like a type.)
Are there any best practices on how to perform such task ?
Thank you.

Comment: Specify `JsonProperty` attribute, if you are using Json.NET

Comment: Can you show us your entire `JSON` string? Your current string is incorrect as per: https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy option it to specify the JSON property in an attribute. If you're using Json.NET you can use `[JsonProperty]` for this. Complete example:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Fields
{
    [JsonProperty("System.AreaPath")]
    public string AreaPath { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("System.TeamProject")]
    public string TeamProject { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("System.IterationPath")]
    public string IterationPath { get; set; }
}

public class Resource
{
    public Fields Fields { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        var resource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Resource>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(resource.Fields.TeamProject);
    }
}
```

JSON (removed the "resource" part to make it a complete JSON document; I assume you know how to handle this if necessary):

```
{
    "fields": {
        "System.AreaPath": "someData",
        "System.TeamProject": "team project",
        "System.IterationPath": "someData"
     }
}
```

Output: `team project`